# Increment digit inside string

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Hi i want to increment the integer values in between the string.
for example the initial string is -- **m1p1b1**.
The below code is working correctly, But it has one problem.
When the string is **m10p10b10** it gives the result **m21p21b21** not **m11p11b11**.
Also the integer length between the string dynamic, So i cant do any static code.

```
  Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
            Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher("m1p1b1");
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
            }
            matcher.appendTail(result);
            System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Change `(\\d)` to `(\\d+)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `\\d` to `\\d+` to match *one or more digits*:

```
Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher("m10p10b10");
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)) + 1));
}
matcher.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // => m11p11b11
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/AJlpuG)

Note you do not have to capture the whole pattern with `(...)`, you can access the value using `matcher.group(0)`.

Comment: How do i do with m.group(0) method?

Comment: See my code demo :) I replaced `matcher.group(1)` with `matcher.group(0)`.  I usually use `m` for a `Matcher` variable name.